# How to save data into multiple table with only single Entity Class in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Do we still have to map All tables to Entity Class in a Spring Hibernate Project ?
I have couple Tables :

```
 - Quote (Transaction)
 - NextNumber 
 - Branch (Master)
```

e.g :

I want to create a numbering like **'QF18-4238/BHP.SI/ISD'**, this numbering will saved in **Quote** Table.

For some Reason:

The Number **'4238'** -> will also saved in **NextNumber** Table.

The **'/BHP.SI/ISD'** -> will lookup from **Branch** Table depending on whos LoggedIn.

```
    If Login as **A** the result will **'/BHP.TMI/MM'**
    else if **B** the result will **''/BHP.SI/ISD**
```

Is it possible to just create one Entity Class ?

please enlighten me

Database Model:

[image]

Comment: can you show how the database model looks like?

Comment: Hi Simon,
Please see the attachment link, just update the post.
fyi, 
- **Employee**, **AddressBook** and **Branch** table are in the different Instance DB.
- User login based on Email in **Employee** Table